# ASP.NET Core 8 Web API - Getting 404 Not Found Status Code in Postman

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, and I tried with a simple method.

[Controller method screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tONd.png)

This screenshot shows my response in [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info):

[image: This image shows my response in postman]

How can I find the solution for this?

I want to get the method returning string "List All Products" in Postman response OK.

Comment: Based on your code, the URL should be `/api/Product/GetProduct` ...

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77659194/edit). Thanks in advance.